# Internet explorer always trigger window onbeforeunload

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

The problem is that the Internet explorer fires every time ... here's my code:

```
    window.onbeforeunload = function() {

        if( !gdymc.info.isSaved && !gdymc.info.isSaving ) {

            return jQuery('#gdymc_adminbar').attr('data-unload');

        } else {

            return null;

        }

    }
```

Is there any known issue with ie? This works on all other browsers just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im pretty sure that you will need to return `undefined` instead of `null`:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    if( !gdymc.info.isSaved && !gdymc.info.isSaving ) {

        return jQuery('#gdymc_adminbar').attr('data-unload');
    } else {
        // returns undefined
        return void 0;
    }
}
```

The above is testet in IE8 and it works.

Comment: Could you also do just `return;`? Do you need `void 0` here?

Comment: @Halcyon yes this is true or simply not return anything which will also resolve in `undefined`

Comment: Yeah just tested it and (this part) work fine. Thanks.